# why my function is not do for loop?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, for-loop, while-loop

In my code if i click button the program in search function.
In search function i have 2 for loop .The frist loop is a loop for data.length and The secound loop is a loop for data.parameter.length. The problem is javascript not do every for loop i didn't know why javascript can't do that this is my code:

```
function searchData(){
  console.log('in function');
    for(var z = 0;z < cloudData.length;z++){
      console.log(z);
      for(var x = 0;x < cloudData.items[z].coordinates[x].length;x++){
        console.log(x);
        if(google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(cloudData.items[z].coordinates[x],poly) == true){
              console.log(true);
              setAllMap(map,'polygon',z);
              return
        }else{
         console.log(false);
        }    
      }     
    }
  deleteDrawings('Userpolygon');
}
```

**The parameter coordinates[x] is type latLng and poly is type polygon in google map api

Program is do console.log() and deleteDrawings('Userpolygon'); function but it didn't do for loop console.log(z); dont'show console.log(x); dont'show. Thank for every ideas.

Comment: Does cloudData have ... data? Do a `console.log('CD:', cloudData)`before the for.

Comment: yes cloudData have a data

Comment: Are you positive that before the for loop it is an Array with `length > 0`? That is the only reasonable explanation for not logging z.

Comment: Oh sorry i see cloudData.length = undefind but cloudData.items.length is has a value

Answer (score 0):

Ok i have Solve my issue. i change `cloudData.length` to `cloudData.items.length`  and change  `cloudData.items[z].coordinates[x].length` to  `cloudData.items[z].coordinates.length`

it is work for me thank every one to read my issue.